# NDSolve emitting error NDSolve:: ndnum

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

```
s = 
  NDSolve[
    {m'[r] == α*r^2 ϵ[r], 
     p'[r] == -(r0/r)*((p[r] + ϵ[r]) (m[r] + α r^3* p[r]))/(r - 2 r0*m[r]), 
     m[10] == 1, p[10.] == 1}, 
    {m, p}, 
    {r, 10, 100}]
```

I have given all the values of the parameters. Need solution for `p[r], m[r]`. But it is showing :

> NDSolve:: ndnum, r, 10.] NDSolve:Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at r == 10.

Can any one solve the problem?

Comment: If my answer works for you, please consider upvoting and accepting it!

Comment: What happens when you plug in r = 10 and the initial condition into the DE and solve for r’? Do you get a numeric value? Or are there undefined symbols?

Comment: It is writing the same equation replacing every parameter with there values except p[r], m[r] and r.

Comment: You should post complete code that will reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give values to both of the parameters and define $\epsilon[r]$. Doing so, works nicely:

```
a=1;
r0=1/100;
e[r_]:=1/r
s=NDSolve[{m'[r]==a*r^2 e[r],p'[r]==-(r0/r)*((p[r]+e[r]) 
(m[r]+a r^3*p[r]))/(r-2r0*m[r]),m[10]==1,p[10]==1},{m,p},{r,10,100}][[1]];

LogPlot[{m[r],p[r]}/.s//Evaluate,{r,10,100},Frame->True,PlotLegends->{"m(r)", "p(r)"}]
```

Feel free to adapt this to your problem.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. I will do this and let you know tomorrow.

Comment: Actually my `e[r_]` is a little complicated. `e[r_]:=3p[r]+4B-(16/27)*mu*T(mu^2-2 mu*T+T^2)`. where `B :=160` and `mu := 10^19`

Comment: I have posted my problem in the answer section of the post. Please check and give me a solution if possible

Comment: Thee problem in this case is that mu (the Planck mass?) is too large and then Mathematica complains about stiffness. Also, you don't give the value of T in your problem. One possible solution would be to redefine all quantities in terms of mu (ie absorb it), so that you don't have huge numbers.

Comment: Btw, for future reference, please always try to post questions will fully working code (=all definitions and values for all parameters) as otherwise we cannot fix the code.

Comment: mu is chemical potential and T=170.  I am sorry. Next time onwards I will post full code.

Comment: You are right Mathematica is complaining about stiffness. So if the mu value is small will it be fine???